# Converting Double to String with ternary operator in Swift

Tags: swift, ternary-operator

Need to eliminate extra zeros when working with doubles in swift eg (3.0 should output like 3 and 3.2 should be 3.2)

```
//description is String; operand is Double

// works
(operand - floor(operand) != 0) ? (description += String(operand)) : (description += String(Int(operand)))

// not works
description += String( (operand - floor(operand) != 0) ? operand : Int(operand) )
```

Why ternary operator is giving an error in second version? Is there any other way to avoid duplicate code?

Comment: When you post a question about an error you need to include the complete and exact error in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of rules regarding using the ternary operator. One of them is that the operand on the left and right side of the `:` character must be of compatible types.

In your code,

```
(operand - floor(operand) != 0) ? operand : Int(operand)
```

The left side of the `:` is a `Double`, while the right side is an `Int`. `Double` and `Int` are not compatible types, so it fails to compile.

A workaround for this:

```
description += "\((operand - floor(operand) != 0) ? operand as AnyObject: Int(operand) as AnyObject)"
// now the two sides are both AnyObjects now!
```

If you want even less duplicate code, in terms of number of characters, you can cast the two operands to `Any` instead of `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 0):

```
description += String( (operand - floor(operand) != 0) ? operand : Int(operand) ).
```

This ternary operation has different result types, double and int.